# How to start activity on animation end

Tags: android

This is my first app and i need to start new activity when the animation ends. what do I need to do? My code:

```
package com.lineage.goddess;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LineageSplashActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        startAnimation();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 

    }

    private void startAnimation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView logo1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        Animation fade1= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        logo1.startAnimation(fade1);
        TextView logo2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
        Animation fade2= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        logo2.startAnimation(fade2);
        TextView logo3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView3);
        Animation fade3= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        logo3.startAnimation(fade3);
        TextView logo4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView4);
        Animation fade4= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
        logo4.startAnimation(fade4);}
         public void onAnimationEnd() {
             Intent i = new Intent( LineageSplashActivity.this, LineageMenuActivity.class );
             LineageSplashActivity.this.startActivity( i );
;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Set an AnimationListener to the animation you want to use to start your Activity.

```
myAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        Intent i = new Intent( LineageSplashActivity.this, LineageMenuActivity.class );
        LineageSplashActivity.this.startActivity( i );
    }
}
```

So, your code will be like this:

```
package com.lineage.goddess;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LineageSplashActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        startAnimation();
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 

    }

    private void startAnimation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView logo1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
        Animation fade1= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        logo1.startAnimation(fade1);
        TextView logo2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
        Animation fade2= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        logo2.startAnimation(fade2);
        TextView logo3= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView3);
        Animation fade3= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        logo3.startAnimation(fade3);
        TextView logo4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView4);
        Animation fade4= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
        face4.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                Intent i = new Intent( LineageSplashActivity.this, LineageMenuActivity.class );
                LineageSplashActivity.this.startActivity( i );
            }
        }    

        logo4.startAnimation(fade4);    
    }
}
```

Comment: please give me full code ... when i pase it after         TextView logo4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView4);
        Animation fade4= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
        logo4.startAnimation(fade4);}
i have :myAnimation cannot be resolved and AnimationListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You should've tried this yourself in my opinion. Anyway, the code is posted in my answer.

Comment: You mean `fade4.setAnimationListener()`?

Comment: Yes, the following is missing after setAnimationListener statement:                                     );

Answer (score 4):

Your code made my eye's bleed, so I fixed it as much as I could:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

public class LineageSplashActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_ANIMATIONS = 4;
    private int animationFinishedCount = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 

        startAnimations();
    }

    private void startAnimations() {
        Animation fade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        fade.setAnimationListener(this);    

        findViewById(R.id.TextView1).startAnimation(fade);
        findViewById(R.id.TextView2).startAnimation(fade);
        findViewById(R.id.TextView3).startAnimation(fade);
        findViewById(R.id.TextView4).startAnimation(fade);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // When all animations have finished - start the next activity
        if(++animationFinishedCount == NUMBER_OF_ANIMATIONS){
            Intent intent = new Intent( this, LineageMenuActivity.class );
            startActivity( intent );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // Nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // Nothing
    }
}
```

And if it's not a mis-type and you actually need a different animation for the 4th textview you can remove the count check and just add the animation listener to that individual animation.