# How can I animate my button's application?

Tags: android, button, android-animation

I want create an application with animate button? how can i do?
after click i want rotate or hide one button..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

> To Animate The Button

Create

> rotate.xml

in `anim` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:duration="1200"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillEnabled="true" />
```

and inside your java code:

```
   Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        myButton.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AbcActivity.this, R.anim.rotate));

    }
});
```

> To Hide the button

```
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Or

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer..
but i've insert this code and it give me one error :(

     bgiusto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   public void onClick(View v) {
    
    
    bgiusto.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate));

    
    int seconds=(int) ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()chrono.getBase())/1000);
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(i-seconds));
       
       intent.putExtra("Punteggio:", i-seconds);
    
       startActivity(intent);
       Livello1_1.this.finish();

   
   }

   
     });

Comment: only another question (if you can)..how can i wait the animation end for start activity with this button? i want that when i press this button, start an anim and after it start another intent with another layout..

Comment: Here you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579246/how-to-start-activity-on-animation-end

Comment: I followed your advice but with this code the activity start firt of the animation end..why??  bgiusto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(View v) {    bsbagliato2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
tableRowliv1_1.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Livello1_1.this, R.anim.rotate)); if(++animationFinishedCount == NUMBER_OF_ANIMATIONS){   
        intent.putExtra("Punteggio:", i-seconds);
     
        startActivity(intent);
        Livello1_1.this.finish();
          }

             }